# how to get concave surface which close to the outer edge point

Tags: qgis, concave-hull

In qgis, how to generate the blue outer edge (the concave surface close to the outer edge point) in Fig. 2 from the point in Fig. 1. Any suggestion?[image]

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the two concave hull processing tool or the concave hull plugin ?

Comment: The answer is the following: 1) run the Delaunay Triangulation tool on the points ... and delete unnecessary triangles in edit mode (pencil); 2) Select Vector> Geoprocessing> Merge By Feature> By All Features ... and create a polygon; 3) Polygons in line and you get the desired result ...